# Error while booting says '/casper/vmlinuz not found’

Tags: 18.04

Just bought a new internal hard disk and made a bootable Ubuntu USB. But while booting it says that `/casper/vmlinuz` not found.

Comment: Please help me with this

Comment: Did you hashcheck the downloaded ISO?  How did you create the bootable USB? did you run a media check on the USB?  Sounds like a bad USB setup, it boots, but can't find a kernel to run.

Comment: Downloaded the iso file from https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads and used rufus3.1 to make bootable usb. Do you have any alternative ways to make bootable usb. I m still having problem to install

Answer (score 2):

1. Does your system meets the minimum requirements for your selected edition? Check that your ISO is for your architecture (32 vs 64 bit).
   See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements
   Lack of enough memory can cause boot failure of the install media. Select a
   lower requirement edition like Lubuntu or Xubutnu if necessary.
2. Did you md5sum check the downloaded iso?   See
   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM   Check the number
   against the listing in the link for your release listed at
   http://releases.ubuntu.com under the MD5SUMS link.   For other
   releases' hashes, like lubuntu, see:
   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes
3. If using a CD/DVD, did you burn the disc as slowly as possible?
   See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto    If using
   USB install media, use a  tool like unetbootin or rufus.     Don't
   just copy files to the USB.
   See     https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick
4. Did you select the media check before trying to install?      See
   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck
5. Did you ever do a "memory check" (perhaps another live-media menu
   choice) on your PC?

Doing the above can save you a lot of time struggling with a bad install media or hardware problems.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, If it is a bootable disk created by Rufus, make sure to run Rufus as Administrator to fix this issue.

In fact, the file was missing from the drive for me when I was creating the disk as non-admin user on Windows